# Maximum command line length in git bash

Tags: gcc, makefile, command-line, command-line-arguments, git-bash

It looks like there is a hardwired limit of 8192 (or so) characters which is substantially less than the 32000 which is reported by

```
getconf ARG_MAX
```

I am using `git bash` as a very convenient (because deployed in a controlled mainstream way) method to run `GNU make` on Windows. The only problem which can sometimes hamper my process is the length of the command line to `gcc` which due to some unchangeable factors has several dozen up to a hundred `-Iinclude_dir` parameters. If you think that evading the problem by changing the latter intricacy would be the wiser option, I am all ears for a solution to that.

Comment: Make a single directory to hold (symlinks to) headers.  Only specify that directory on the command line to GCC.  It probably won't be quite that simple if some headers are in the form `#include "subdir/header.h"` — you'll need a main include directory `$PROJECT/include` with a sub-directory `subdir` holding the symlink `header.h` that points to where the original is found.  There may still be problems, but even reducing "up to a 100" down to under 10 would be a major improvement.

Comment: Not using Windows is always a wonderful solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://www.betaarchive.com/wiki/index.php/Microsoft_KB_Archive/830473 Command line length limit on Windows is 2047 or 8191, depending on OS version.

Because of this limitation, many Windows developer tools accept "[response files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/midl/response-files)" which are text files containing arguments. GCC [supports this](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-10.2.0/gcc/Overall-Options.html#:%7E:text=%40file,-Read) too.

Answer (score 0):

ARG_MAX is actually the total command line limit.
something innocuous like

`funky.py $(find . -name '*.java')`

can exceed that limit if there are 1600 or so files
for some reason grep is ok when I do that.
I don't know why